# Saving character to string type on to the stack?

Tags: c++

I have a stack defined and it accepts only strings. 
Now my goal is to read each character, if it is operator like +, I need to push it to the stack.

when i push it, it saves the ACSII calue of + which is 43

how do i achieve to save char in to string?

i tried to use STL

```
stack<string> s1;
    string post;
    if (exp[0] == '+')
    {
        s1.push(to_string(exp[0]));
    }
    cout<<s1.top();
```

i need to save +, eventually i am writing code to convert infox to postfix expression. My input will be numbered with operators

Comment: why can't you do s1.push("+"); you already know it is going to be a +, because you are checking for it.

Comment: i am scanning using for loop to check for operators and then push it to the string stack

Comment: like I said, why can't you do s1.push("+"), it seems to me your stack can just be stack<char> s1

Comment: but i am assigned to use string stack of my own and make infix to postfix expression. i am confused now

Comment: KEEP THE CODE YOU HAVE and tell me why you can't just change s1.push(to_string(exp[0])); to s1.push("+");

Comment: or string(1,exp[0])

Comment: The last one worked. I want to make the simple and readable code for the expression evaluator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`to_string` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) only has overloads for converting numerical values to strings, which is why you're getting the string "43".  You could just change your code to this:

```
s1.push("+");
```

in which string's [from c-string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) constructor is used to implicitly convert from the `const char*` to a `string`.  Alternately, to convert from a single `char` to a `string`, the easiest way is to use the [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), in which case you would write this:

```
s1.push(string(1, exp[0]));
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. I am very new to C++ who is interested to explore more. I was just seeing the way around to work with to_string. could you please explain how to approach this kind of issues and explore more c++ functionalities.

Comment: I am trying to understand this, when we call this function , string(1, exp[0]) , it is constructor of string class? Before it sends it to stack push function, how does this work?

Comment: It is a constructor of the string class that takes in size of string with the value. More can be read here for overloaded versions: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/